# Symfony 5 - Add select form elements in a loop in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like to add form elements in a twig template, but in a loop as shown there :
[Example 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwG8l.png)

Example of the code I'd need for one select element :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('quantity', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'choices' => [0,10,20,30]
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class,[
                'label' => $this->translator->trans('Enregistrer les quantités')
            ]);
        $form->getForm();
```

But I'm not that confident with dynamic forms, so first, how can I create multiform element in my controller depends on the number of line elements, pass them to my template and then display them in my twig template ?

Also, Is it possible to have ONE button to update all select elements ?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Have a look at the [Collection Type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

Comment: Hi @El_Vanja, interesting ! I'll check this option ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

let say your lines are product, and your select is an attribute of your line( so of your product).

You could use imbrication form to solve this problem:

in your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductsType::class, null, ['products'=>$allMyProductEntities);
```

then describe ProductsType as follow:

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        for($product as $options['products']){
            $builder->add('product', ProductType::class, [
                 'label' => false,
                 'entity' => $product,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class
            'products' => [],
        ));
    }
}
```

then describe ProductType as follow:

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public $translator

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator){
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('quantity', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'choices' => [0,10,20,30],
                'default' => $option['entity']->getQuantity(),
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
            'entity' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

(Don't add submit button in your form here, do it in twig, it is best practice)
then you can loop on your form in twig:

```
{% for product in form.products %}
<li>
    {{ form_widget(product.quantity) }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Florent, thank you for your suggestion. I'm not used to work with FormType as you advice me, I always build my forms in controllers as I use them only once. I'll check your solution and try to study how FormTypes work. Also I'll mixe with the comment of El_Vanja regarding CollectionType. Regards.